# How to detect if a command is interactive or not in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, tee

I want to save the output for specific subprocesses for later use. For this I use tee to show the output to stdout and a logging file. However when it comes to interactive commands like ncdu or htop or something like that it of course can't write that properly into a file. Therefore I want to be able to know if a command is interactive or not either before running it (which is not possible I think) or whilst reading the messed up logging file of such a command. I would assume that there is something that an interactive program writes to stdout that a normal command wouldn't and that would allow me to distinguish the two.

Comment: In C, you have function isatty. In interactiv mode, 1 should be a tty.

Comment: `I would assume that there is something that an interactive program writes to stdout that a normal command wouldn't` Well, there isn't. So no, you can't. You can build a list of programs and options where you would want to apply your filtering. Anyway, you are asking XY problem, as it seems to me you want to use `script` for log interactive _sessions_.

Comment: `grep ncurses binaryfile >/dev/null && echo NCURSES || echo no ncurses` <== just kinda kidding!

Comment: @mmeisson That's a different problem. He wants to know if a command that he's running from the script is interactive (full-screen), not if the script is being run interactively.

Answer (score 1):

The "messed up output" is the output intermixed with terminal control sequences, most commonly [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_codes).

For binaries that rely on Curses for terminal output, running the command with the TERM environment variable unset or set to an empty string, causes the command to fail.  For example,

```sh
$ env TERM= htop
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

This is because these standard libraries examine the TERM environment variable, to find the corresponding entry in the terminal database. (The [tput](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) utility uses that database too, so you can use `tput clear` to clear the terminal, `tput reset` to reset the terminal to a default state (useful if something garbles the terminal mode), and so on.)

To find out if `command` is compiled with ncurses/curses or terminal info database ([terminfo](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) support, you can run e.g. `ldd command | grep -qe 'libn*curses' -e 'libtinfo' && echo Yes || echo No`.
However, this does only tells whether these commands properly support different terminals, not whether they require a terminal to work.

Then there are also scripts and tools, like `ls --color`, which do not use curses or terminfo support, and instead emit ANSI control sequences directly.  (In the case of `ls`, the sequences defined in the `LS_COLORS` environment variable are used, but only if the output is to a terminal.  As mentioned by mmeisson in a comment to the original question, this is trivial to detect using e.g. [isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).)

In the case of `htop`, we cannot even use the dumb terminal (set TERM to dumb, before running the command, i.e. `env TERM=dumb htop </dev/null &>output`), because htop renders the task list as all spaces! Very annoying.  At least with `top` (`env TERM=dump top </dev/null &>output`) one gets nice, unadorned ASCII output.

The vanilla terminal might be sufficient.  Before executing the child process or command, set `TERM=vanilla` and `COLUMNS=80`, for example `env TERM=vanilla COLUMNS=80 htop </dev/null &>output`. However, although you now get more output from `htop`, newlines are still missing (because htop uses cursor movements exclusively, and the vanilla terminal does not have those).

There might be another terminal that works for you, say, one where all escape sequences generated would be easy to detect and filter out, but is complex enough for e.g. htop output to be complete.  I don't know one, though.  You could create one, and add it to one of the terminfo databases (say, as `/etc/terminfo/e/easy`).  (You can list all terminfo files your machine has using `ls -1 {/etc,/lib,/usr/share}/terminfo/?/* | sed -e 's|^.*/||g' | sort` . Mine has over 2700.)

There is a distinct, "proper" solution for this type of problem, but it isn't easy.

Instead of using just pipes to the subprocesses, you use a proper pseudoterminal interface, [pty](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), specifically UNIX98 pseudoterminals via [posix_openpt()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_openpt.3.html), [grantpt()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/grantpt.3.html), [unlockpt()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlockpt.3.html), and [ptsname()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ptsname.3.html).  However, the master side – your process – must then behave like a real terminal, and handle all the control sequences it advertises it supports (by having the TERM environment variable set to the terminal type).

There are some terminal emulator libraries and code you can reuse for your own project; the ones that immediately come to my mind are [VTE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/) (which uses a GTK+ GUI widget for the terminal display) and [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/) itself; the `ctlseqs.txt` in xterm sources is an excellent list of the actual sequences used in xterm variants.  Another useful project is [GNU screen](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/).

Essentially, your program then *becomes* the terminal the command uses, and can provide the input to the command, and performs all changes the command wants to do on the terminal display.  All you need to do is record those changes somehow.  (This is often called *scraping*, but as the pseudoterminal master, you really just decide how you wish to store the terminal contents: as a movie-like playback, a single screen of some size, or some other way.)

Overall, I'd say the best option would be to use `TERM=xterm` or variant, or perhaps `TERM=ansi`, and just filter out or replace some/most/all of the escape sequences to get the output you want.  Replace the "move cursor to" commands to newlines, followed by the proper number of spaces if the column is greater than 1 (leftmost column); and "clear screens" with one or more newlines.  It's not perfect, but it should be doable as a simple state machine (that reads the terminal output character by character, and emits the filtered output, using standard <stdio.h> functions), and work well enough for most purposes.

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer! Although I think that manipulating the ENV variables to filter out the escape characters is probably a little tricky and I dont know if its that portable if I want other people using this shell and it fiddles around with their environment variables and they dont even notice it